# How prevent view under navbar in iMessage app extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-app-extension, imessage, imessage-extension

I have the same issue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886318/ios-10-imessage-app-extension-how-do-i-calculate-the-height-of-the-extra-tall-n), i follow all recommended in that answers but notting works, in my case the difference is that i have a table view controller.

> I have tried in many ways to prevent this from happening.

**example:**

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    //the next 2 lines was tested with self.tableView and self.view
    [self.view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor constant:8.0].active = YES;
    [self.view constraintEqualToAnchor:[self.topLayoutGuide bottomAnchor]].active = YES;

    [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0, 0, 0)];

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
}
```

Inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

This is my `UITableViewController` config:

[image]

This is exactly my problem:

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried 'Under Top Bars'?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup, yes in my screenshot is disable. Should be enable? That makes sense?

Comment: Well, you want it to be 'UNDER' the top bar, so yes, i would think that might help.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup not works. same result

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with disabling under navigation bar appearance in your view controller? 
Put following in your init:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

I've used [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) AutoLayout library for setting up constraints and following snippet worked:

```
[_collectionView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

    make.left.equalTo(self.view.mas_left);
    make.top.equalTo(self.view.mas_top);
    make.right.equalTo(self.view.mas_right);
}];
[_collectionView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:[self.bottomLayoutGuide bottomAnchor]].active = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use constraints to the view.

Set a top View constraint for the compact view like:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *searchViewTopConstraints;
```

Update your constraint on compact and expanded view in presentRecentsViewControllerFor:

```
-(void)presentRecentsViewControllerFor:(MSConversation*)conversation withPresentStyle:(MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle)presentationStyle
{
  tableViewC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainInterface" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShareRecents"];
  if (presentationStyle == MSMessagesAppPresentationStyleCompact) {
     NSLog(@"Compact view");
     tableViewC.searchViewTopConstraints.constant = 0;         
  } else
  {
    NSLog(@"Expanded view");
    [self.view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:[self.topLayoutGuide bottomAnchor]].active = YES;
  }
}
```